# “No such file or directory in..”

Tags: php, include-path

I have folder in htdocs named includes where I have for example header.php. Then I have a file outside the folder namned index.php. I use include("includes/header.php"); in the index.php file to include the header, but I get "include(includes/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/lih/public_html/index.php". What am I doing wrong?

Perhaps important to add, this works on my computer but does not work on the servers.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
    <title><?= $site_title . $divider . $page_title; ?></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/mainmenu.css" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header id="mainheader">
            <h1>Välkommen</h1>
   <!--inkluderar mainmenu-->
            <?php include("includes/mainmenu.php"); ?>
        </header>

        <section id="leftcontent">
```

```html
<?php
$page_title = "Startsida";
include("includes/header.php");
?>
<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='css/index.css' /> 
<h2>Startsidan</h2>

        <section id="leftcontent">
            <h2>svar</h2>
            <p>text </p>
        </section>

<?php
include("includes/checklog.php");
```

Comment: Use absolute url for it. `absolute url` means full path of the file. Eg: `http://example.com/includes/file.php` and not this `includes/file.php`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [get "No such file or directory in.."](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40563215/get-no-such-file-or-directory-in)

Comment: Asking the same again(

Comment: I don't believe you have an `includes/header.php` file relative to the `index.php` remember that Unix systems are case-sensitive, so `Includes` != `includes` and it's more efficient to use the full path with `include(__DIR__.'/includes/header.php');` because it will check everywhere else in the [include path](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.include-path) first before finally resolving the local relative path.

Comment: Thanks @JeffPuckettII ! Did not know that Unix system where case-sensitive. That helpt a lot! :)